# Change existing code to select based on proximity

Tags: javascript, html, adjustment

Current HTML snippet:

```
<ul class="ShippingProviderList">
  <li>
    <label id="shippingMethod_500dae76abe48_0">
      <input id="shippingCheck_500dae76abe48" type="radio" value="0" name="selectedShippingMethod[500dae76abe48]" />
      <span class="ShipperName">My Own Shipping Account (Please make sure that account number is specified within your account page or item will not ship!)</span>
      <em class="ShipperPrice ProductPrice">$0.00</em>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li> 2nd option may or may not be here </li>
</ul>
```

Current Javascript snippet:

```
<script>
var radio = document.getElementById('shippingCheck_500d6aa9a300e'),
var input1 = document.getElementById('FormField_25'),
input2 = document.getElementById('FormField_26'),
btn = document.getElementById('ML20').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

btn.onclick = function(e) {
if( radio.checked && input1.value.length >= 20 && input2.value.length >= 20 ) {
    alert('Please provide a Shipping Account Number in either the Billing or Shipping sections in order to use your own Shipping Account.');
    e.preventDefault(); // we all stop the submit from happening.
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
// otherwise do something or nothing and let the submit happen.
};
</script>
```

The problem is that the 500d shipping check is randomly generated, and I have no control over such. is it possible to adjust the Javascript to pull the proper data by say using the span class "ShipperName" that has the term My Own Shipping in it, then pull the input field before that? or is there a better way to do this that I am missing? I am not able to assign an ID, Class, or change the actual html generated there in any way.

Comment: If you can use jQuery you could use .siblings(":radio") I think. It would grab the radio input based on the original selector.

Comment: Note that indenting code to indicate containment helps readability. A decent code editor or IDE will do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jQuery is acceptable, you can use this:

```
$("input[id^='shippingCheck']")
```

Using normal Javascript, you can use this function:

```
function wildcard(startingId){
  // get all inputs
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  // iterate over them
  for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) {

    if ( inputs[i].nodeType === 1 ) {
      // id start with 'shippingCheck' ?
      if (inputs[i].id.indexOf(startingId) == 0)
      {
         return inputs[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
wildcard("shippingCheck")
```

---

You can try this:

```
function fetchInput() {
    var input;
    $(".ShipperName").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf("My Own Shipping Account") != -1)
        {
            input = $(this).prev().get(0);
            return;
        }
    });
    return input;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
fetchInput();
```

The function returns the DOM element, so you can access the `id` attribute, for example, like this:

```
var inputId = fetchInput().id;
```

---

You basically just want your `radio` variable to be a reference to the DOM element, right? So you would use this:

```
var radio = fetchInput();
```

Comment: will this still work as there will be other radio options that also start with shippingcheck?

Comment: The function will return the first input starting with "shippingCheck". If that's what you want, then yes, it will work.

Comment: returning the first will not work unfortunately :( - it really has to somehow pull from the exact name...
I appreciate the attempt though!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you need the exact name, you can use `wildcard("shippingCheck").id` What one do you want to return?

Comment: there could be 1, 4, or 20 different options, all of which generate the same "shippingCheck" id at the beginning, the ID I am after (only the own shipping method) may not even be part of which are generated.

Comment: @NRGdallas - What about this? It gets the input before the element with a `class` attr of "ShipperName" and contains the string "My Own Shipping Account".

Comment: that would work, how would it properly be referenced in my current code? I am honestly really bad/new at javascript ><

Comment: not sure how to implement this into my current javascript; any chance you can toss an example of how it goes into what I currently have?

Comment: I believe this works properly, going to do a bit more testing on another PC (work is closing up), but it looks to be working. Thanks a TON!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using jQuery:

```
var radio = $('[id^="shippingCheck"]');
```

This will find an element with an id that begins with the string "shippingCheck".

Comment: won't work, its possible that other elements will have id's that begin with shippingcheck (such as fedex, ups, etc).

Answer (score 0):

```
var spans = ​document.getElementsByTagName("span"),​​​​​​ span, i, len, node;

​for (i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++) {
    span = spans[i];
    if (span.innerHTML.match(/My Own Shipping/)) {
        node = span;
        while (node && node.nodeName !== "INPUT") {
            node = node.previousSibling;
        }
        console.log(node);  // This is the input element before that SPAN.
        break;        
    }
}
```

A DOM traversal library would make that much simpler.​​  For instance, with jQuery:

```
console.log($("span:contains(My Own Shipping)").prev("input")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var radio = $('.ShipperName:contains("My Own Shipping")').siblings(':radio');
```

It will find a radio button next to a  `.ShipperName` that contains "My Own Shipping".

Comment: non-functional; it skips right past the part where it requires requires the var radio.

Comment: What do you mean it skips past it? Can you clarify what exactly it is you are trying to do? What code do you have so far?

Comment: it simply acts as though var radio has no value, skipping past the if statement afterward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the previous element by pure javascript, you can use the `previousSibling` property with some checking, like the function below. The parameter n is the span element in your case.

```js
function getPreviousSibling(n) {
    var x = n.previousSibling;
    while (x.nodeType != 1) { // check if it's an element node
        x = x.previousSibling;
    }
    return x;
}
```

However, if you get the previous input element of the span with class 'ShipperName', you will get more than one radio inputs (because you might have more than one item in the list). You still need to do extra stuff the get the one you want, but at least you can use the id of the radio input and do something with it.

See [the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/FXeZZ/1/).

It would be easier to select elements if you use jQuery.